# Toggling setInterval animation on/off

Tags: javascript, if-statement, toggle, setinterval

New to js and learning a lot but in all my research I can't get this quite right.
Goal:
1: I have image1 
2: when clicked on runs a setinterval function between image2 and image3, animating it.
3: when clicked on again clearinterval and goes to a static image1.

bonus: no audio when static, plays audio when animate.
I get caught on the thirdstep.

onclick function

```
function clickio() 
{
 element=document.getElementById('myimage')
 if (element.src.match("image2.png","image3.png"))
   {
   clearInterval("animate()");
   element.src="image1.png";
   audiofile.pause();
   }
 else
   {
   audiofile.play();
   setInterval("animate()", 500)
   }
}
```

Animate function

```
function startfire()
{
 element=document.getElementById('myimage')
 if (element.src.match("flame1.png"))
   {
   element.src="flame2.png";
   }
 else
   {
   element.src="flame1.png";
   }
}
```

Example at: [Audibreeze](http://audibreeze.com)

another issue is playing audio via various browsers. 
I used the HTML5 `<audio>` tag 
but had a fall to `<embed>` tag that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your animation problem.

```
var animInterval = null;

var clickio = function( event ){
    var element = document.getElementById( 'myimage' );
    if( interval ){
        clearInterval( animInterval );
        element.src = "image1.png";
        audiofile.pause();
    }
    else{
        audiofile.play();
        animInterval = setInterval( startfire , 500 );
    }
}
```

But I have a few suggestions you might wanna take into account.

1. When creating animations it's usually better to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` if you use HTML5 or a function that mimics that (like this:)

   ```
   window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
       return  window.requestAnimationFrame   || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
           function( callback ){
               window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
           };
   })();
   ```
2. Consider preloading the images before you animate them, or even put all images in the same file (sprite) and changing a background position.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is great if you're tweening properties, but alternating between images is better with a fixed frame rate. You could do that with `requestAnimationFrame`, but `setInterval` better fits the use for that.

Comment: Thank you, I have research about requestAnimationFrame and am working with that now. I can get the animation to work if I call it directly from the on `onclick` command but am having issues when trying to plug it into the switch I built.`function switcher() {
/*counts to 4 then resets to 0*/
 x = x+1
 if (x>3) {x = 0}

 /* Fire OFF */
 if (x == 0) {/*code*/}

 }

/* Fire LARGE */
 if (x == 1) {/*code*/}
        
 }

/* Fire MEDIUM */
 if (x == 2) {/*code*/
 }

/* Fire SMALL */
 if (x == 3) {/*code*/
 }}`

Comment: Find the new quest [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505240/cycle-through-animations-on-click)